# Can Chernoff's Inequality be applied to any random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

Can Chernoff's Inequality be applied to any random variable or is it restricted to the random variables which are summation of 0-1 random variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by Chernoff's Inequality you mean
$$P\{X \geq a\} \leq E[\exp(\lambda(X-a))]~~ \text{for all}~\lambda \geq 0$$
then it applies to all random variables. It is a consequence of the fact that
$\mathbf 1_{[a,\infty)} \leq \exp(\lambda(x-a))$ and so $E[\mathbf 1_{[a,\infty)}] = P\{X \geq a\}$ is bounded above by $E[\exp(\lambda(X-a))]$.